# Form submit delay untill jquery ajax complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ajaxq

Here my process. After i click submit button jquery ajax will trigger and send data to my one database connection. After successfully that i want to redirect my current form data to another web page. Until jquery ajax request complete, I want to delay my form process. How can I do it?

**I'm not asking about .delay function

Answer (score 0):

An AJAX request from jQuery returns a [Promise](https://promisesaplus.com/); one approach you can take is to add handlers for when the Ajax request completes:

```
$.ajax(myOptions)
 .then(function(response) {
     // do redirect
 },function(err) {
     // handle error
 });
```